# Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; Over SSL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I have recently installed a Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate on this [WordPress website](https://www.impression.qa). Everything is working as it should be, but I'm receiving the following error:

> Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block:
>   expected semicolon at character position 14. The default protections
>   will be applied.

I have the following code via .htaccess in my root directory:

```
# X-XSS-Protection
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

The code looks correct to me. Why could I be receiving this error via the console? I was not receiving this error before installing the certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your server sends in the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Link: <https://www.impression.qa/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://www.impression.qa/>; rel=shortlink
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
...
```

As you can see it sends several headers twice, including X-XSS-Protection. Such duplicate headers will the be interpreted like it would have been a single header with all the values joined by ',', i.e.

```
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block
```

And this is invalid for the X-XSS-Protection header and therefore you get the error message. Check your nginx configuration so that you don't send the header twice.